# Ordernar SQL por 1,2,3 ao invés de 1,10,2,3

Tags: sql, sql-server, order

Possuo um campo de nome em uma tabela que possui os seguintes dados:

> 1-Curso
>
> 2-Curso
>
> 10-Curso

Ao ordernar por nome ele retorna `1,10,2`. Como fazer ordenar para trazer: `1,2,10` ?

Ps: O campo é `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se o formato do campo seguir sempre o mesmo padrão, você pode capturar a parte antes do traço e converter para um número, ordenando então o resultado por este valor.

Exemplo:

```sql
select *, 
  CONVERT(INT, LEFT(nome, CHARINDEX('-', nome) - 1)) AS ORDEM
from TESTE
order by ORDEM
```

### [Demo no SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/025df/8)

No entanto, considere que esta é uma solução bem pouco eficiente já que não fará uso de índices no banco de dados.

O ideal seria você criar outra coluna numérico e armazenar o número de ordenação nela no momento da gravação ou atualização do registro.

Comment: Eu diria que, *dado o cenário proposto pelo OP*, esta é a solução mais eficiente.

Comment: @OnoSendai, quais os motivos que levam a crer que essa solução é a mais eficiente, embasado em que (sinceridade, me surgiu essa dúvida)?

Comment: @Maria o termo-chave é 'cenário proposto'. Dadas as limitações impostas pelo OP, não consigo imaginar outra solução que seja mais curta, direta ou simples.

Comment: @OnoSendai eu pensei que era embasado em algo técnico visto que as duas respostas abaixo não fogem muito a essa... mas, obrigada !!!

Comment: @Maria foi mais um comentário em cima de um trecho da resposta: '[...]considere que esta é uma solução bem pouco eficiente[...]'. Não foi um comparativo com as outras respostas; todas se basearam no mesmo princípio de *parsing* e conversão.

Comment: Por isso que eu fiz a pergunta @OnoSendai queria entender o porque talvez de ser mais eficiente, foi mesmo tecnicamente falando, aprendizado... entendeu!

Answer (score 4):

Como não foi passado o layout da tabela eu coloque nome e tabela nos referentes lugares:

**SQL**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(nome, 0, CHARINDEX('-', nome)), nome
FROM tabela ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(nome, 0, CHARINDEX('-', nome)))
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5e5f/1)

Answer (score 3):

Parte da pergunta você já respondeu: O campo é `nvarchar`, logo ele ordena alfabeticamente caractere por caractere.

Para ordenar da maneira que você deseja é preciso antes extrair a parte numérica e transformar em `int`.

Assumindo que essa coluna siga um padrão (número seguido de um traço, seguido de algo), você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
SELECT curso 
FROM tabela
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(curso , CHARINDEX('-', curso) - 1))
```

Porém, se possível, quebre sua coluna em duas, uma parte numérica e outra parte texto, para evitar esse tipo de query.

Comment: pq o downvote ?

Comment: eu votei a favor ta certo ...!!! agora quem votou contra não sei.